# HTML Tag datalist : how can I align the behaviour of datalist so that it behave the same in Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, web, firefox

I encounter the problem that Firefox and chrome displays datalist in different ways: 
[image]
[image]

Chrome displays the innertext and the value but Firefox only shows innertext. How can I fix that?

Even after a solid hour of trying and googling, I still have no idea how to fix it.

```
<input list="languages" id="language_id">
    <datalist id="languages">
        <option value="In chrome I am visible as well">Firefox only shows me</option>
    </datalist>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k7mspr4a/)